# How to make sure that the user can only submit specific pattern while inserting a value into an input?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, regex

I was wondering if I have a form and the form contain some inputs that I want the user to be only able to submit a type of inputs I select , Like if I want to make sure that the password contain at least a CAPITAL letter , a number , a symbol and at least 8 letters , How to make sure even if the Javascript is disabled by the user?

Comment: check on the server-side... anybody can post anything to your website, you cannot prevent it. 
However, HTML5 has introduced regular expression patterns for form elements, but they aren't very flexible for checking a password policy.

Answer (score 2):

### Brief

You'll want to minimalize the checking on the client-side. Any checking done at this point is pretty useless when security and/or validation is concerned. I would suggest doing a simple validation (such as minimum length) but nothing else as any method you try client-side can easily be circumvented.

Doing all your validation server-side prevents users from editing client-side code or disabling JavaScript to prevent validation. As an added bonus, if you do everything server-side (and use minimal validation client-side) it increases maintainability since you're only defining your patterns once and you don't have to worry about compatibility across multiple regex engines (which is a pain).

For example, character classes (such as `\p{L}`) allow you to specify groups of Unicode characters. These are fantastic when you're talking about ensuring your program works well with multiple languages (i.e. French and the inclusion of characters such as `é`), but they're not available in HTML or JavaScript!

You should:

- Define the pattern once (coders don't like duplication)
- Do the validation server-side (forget about *true* validation client-side, anything you implement at this step can easily be bypassed). **[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)**
- When you're talking about password validation don't limit the characters to specific ranges (as your pattern would client-side using something like `[A-Z]`). You may think this increases password strength, but it may actually do exactly the opposite. Instead, allow users to use special characters as well (it's simple but using `Ä` is more secure than `A`).

---

### Code

#### Client-Side

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\w_]).{8,}
```

**Although, honestly, I'd suggest simply using `.{8,}` and doing the checks solely on the server-side.**

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" pattern="(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\w_]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one uppercase letter, number and symbol, and at least 8 or more characters"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

#### Server-Side

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/klP1bv/1)

```
^(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{N})(?=.*[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{C}]).{8,}$
```

**Usage**

Where `$str` in the code below is the submitted password

```
$re = '^(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{N})(?=.*[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{C}]).{8,}$';
if(preg_match($re, $str)) {
    // Valid password
} else {
    // Invalid password - provide user feedback and allow them to try again
}
```

---

### Explanation

The HTML regex is just a simpler variation of the regex below (without using Unicode classes). I would, once again, suggest using `.{8,}` for the pattern in HTML and let PHP do the actual password validation.

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?=.*\p{Lu})` Positive lookahead ensuring at least one uppercase Unicode character exists
- `(?=.*\p{N})` Positive lookahead ensuring at least one Unicode number exists
- `(?=.*[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{C}])` Positive lookahead ensuring at least one character that isn't a letter, number, or control character exists (includes punctuation, symbols, separators, marks)
- `.{8,}` Match any character 8 or more times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

This is not simple to answer as it is written but here is the idea.

First check client-side using javascript, match it against the desired pattern before allowing submit.  There are a handfull of libraries out there if you dont want to puzzle it out yourself.

Second, and to satisfy the no javascript issue, check server-side.  The user may have gotten past your form with faulty data but a server-side check will ensure that it matches what you like before you actually make a change to your database.